# Compress a folder with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that I want automatically compress with a script to make space. For that, I use the following script for a folder called 'test':

```
$a = Get-Item "D:\Aither\Pca\Test"
$a.Attributes += "Compressed"
```

After some tests, the attribute "hidden" works with the previous code but not with the attribute "Compressed"

[image]

Compress contents to save disk space should be checked. Even when turning off my computer, it's not working.

Did I make a mistake in my code or it's just a rights issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to your answer -- there is a native command

```
Enable-NtfsCompression [-Path] <String[]> [-Recurse] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: This command is not recognized by my powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I found a answer with the following code :

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path "Win32_Directory.Name='D:\Aither\Pca\Test'" -Name compress
```